# Accelerate computation speed by using a different syntax

Tags: matlab, gpu, acceleration

I was reading a book about Matlab (["Accelerating Matlab with GPU computing - A Primer with Examples" by Jung Suh and Youngming Kim](https://www.elsevier.com/books/accelerating-matlab-with-gpu-computing/suh/978-0-12-408080-5), 2013. Chapter 1.7 Examples).

I read an example where it said that:

> by using elemental calculation, matrix calculation, and function call
>   instead of for loops, the speed can be dramatically accelerated.

In the case I read, it reduced calculation time from 50s to 0.5s.

My questions:

1. which syntax is more "resources saving" and "faster": `function call`, `for`, `while`, `if`, `switch`, and (i.e. search elements in a matrix or set) etc.?
2. How fast is the element-wise calculation, addition, and matrix calculation etc.?

For the convince of understanding, a short example was given below:

```
%%% First case
tic;
B = 0;
A = 1:1e8;
for i=1:1000
    B = B + A(i);
end
toc;

%%% Second case
tic;
B = 0;
A = 1:1e8;
B = sum(A);
toc;

%%% Third case
C = ones(1e8,1);
tic;
B = 0;
A = 1:1e8;
B = A*C;
toc;
```

with the following timing results

Elapsed time is **0.463159** seconds.

Elapsed time is **0.501524** seconds.

Elapsed time is **0.532470** seconds.

In the above example, all three methods had different but comparable speed.

Comment: Can you provide the information about the book you are reading?

Comment: I think that you are referring to vectorization of operations, am I right?

Comment: @nicoguaro Some of this is also down to the generic optimisation differences between compiled and interpreted code.

Comment: As per our discussion on Meta, several people think that this question is indeed on-topic; however, it is a bit too broad to answer it. @J C, if you add a book reference/code example/computation description, I would be happy to nominate this question for reopening.

Comment: I still think it is too broad, since the answer will be very different depending on *what* you try to compute. It also very much depends on the version of Matlab (and, to a degree, the hardware and operating system since matrix operations are punted to the Intel MKL library); as you notice, simple(!) `for` loops have become much faster in recent versions of Matlab compared to a few years ago.

Comment: @ChristianClason, with this comment, you actually partially answered the very question that J C has. From the top of my head, the codes above in earlier versions of Matlab would have a major disparity (don't have Matlab license to test). Now, Matlab is using vectorization and code optimization techniques better. However, that will not be quite true for, say, `numpy`: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483042/explain-the-speed-difference-between-numpys-vectorized-function-application-vs)

Comment: Instead of trying to think of it in terms of which Matlab syntax is faster, which I think is a bit of a dead end, try thinking more concretely in terms of what actually gets executed on the CPU: is it running a (slow, non-JIT) interpreter over your code, or is execution dispatched to a compiled optimized function. Trying to classify different aspects of Matlab's syntax as fast or slow wouldn't get at the underlying issues and wouldn't help understand.